# Does casting Sleep affect the caster if they are within range of point of origin?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Debating this with DM. Sleep can be cast with a point of origin a distance from the caster, but if the cube extends back to the caster is the caster affected or immune?

Comment: It's a different spell, but the rules are the same. The spell affects creatures in the area, if you're in the area, you're affected.